# Erro ao conectar o MySQL no VScode com c++

Tags: mysql, c++, visual-studio-code

Estou tentando conectar o ***MySQL*** à algum tempo no ***VScode*** com o ***SO linux mint +19***, e não estou conseguindo após ter feito os seguintes passos:

Baixei o Connector no site da MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/

com os seguintes arquivos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dentro da **pasta include** tem os arquivos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dentro da **pasta lib64** tem os arquivos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e coloquei os arquivos da **pasta include** em -> `/usr/include/`
e os arquivos da **pasta lib64** coloquei em -> `/usr/lib/`

O código que fiz no VScode foi bem simples:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <jdbc/mysql_connection.h>
#include <jdbc/mysql_driver.h>
#include <jdbc/cppconn/exception.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace sql;

int main(void)
{

    sql::Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *con;

    cout << "connecting to mysql server....";
    driver = get_driver_instance();
    con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "leandro", "root");  
    cout << "connected" << endl;

    delete con;

}
```

[image]

quando eu tento executar o código acima da o seguinte erro:

> /tmp/ccBhXaG2.o: Na função "main":
>   tempCodeRunnerFile.cpp:(.text+0x2f): referência não definida para "get_driver_instance"
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: ao invés de colocar um **print** do código, coloque o código mesmo.

Comment: fica todo bugado os includes quando eu tento colocar o código..

Comment: Coloquei parte do código, a parte dos includes não foi possível.

Comment: A exibição do código era só questão de formatação.